# PHP multidimensional array algorithm?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to form an multidimensional array as below format however I could not figure out the algorithm

```
array(
      [0]=>array(
            "id"=>"1","data"=>array([0]=>array("kid"=>"434","k"=>"Ali","m"=>"msj1"), [1]=>array("kid"=>"344","k"=>"Dali","m"=>"msj3")),
      [1]=>array(
            "id"=>"2","data"=>array([0]=>array("kid"=>"347","k"=>"Cenk","m"=>"msj2"), [1]=>array("kid"=>"345","k"=>"Tan","m"=>"msj4")))
```

the data comes from mysql query like below:

> SELECT kid, k, m, id FROM table1 WHERE rid=1 ORDER BY (id)

sample data:

```
id   kid   k    m
1    434  Ali  msj1
2    347  Cenk msj2
1    344  Dali msj3
2    345  Tan  msj4
```

php loop is as below:

```
do {
//whatever I tried here failed :(
} while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tav));
```

I hope that I will understand multidimensional arrays better with this sample

Comment: do-while is not your friend here as you will not be able to access the $t array in the loop.

Comment: Ali Aktaş, edit example array please, so i can help better

Comment: i think there should be a dummy variable to check if "id" change or not. depending on the change of id a new array to hold other data arrays should be formed. But some how i cant write down the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arrRows = mysql_fetch_array($r_tav);
$arrRowData = array();
$arrRowDataFinal = array();
foreach ($arrRows as $key => $value){
    $arrRowData[$value['id']][] = array("kid"=>$value['kid'],"k"=>$value['k'],"m"=>$value['m']);
}
foreach($arrRowData as $key => $value){
    $arrRowDataFinal[] = array('id' => $key, 'data' => $value);
}
```

Comment: i tried the code, i generates the arrays in right format however it fails to collect data in common "id" arrays. i will work on to generate correct output

Comment: your solution is correct one, except we need to form the array of raw data in to $arrRows.. i do that with code of 
`$t = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tav);
$row_sayi = mysql_num_rows($r_tav);
if ($row_sayi > 0) {
do {
$tav_a[]=$t;
$op=$t;
} while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tav)); 
}
$arrRows = $tav_a;`

betters ways of generating above array is welcome..

tahnks Poonam,  thanks stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

It seemed like all you want is:

```
while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tav)){
    $arr[] = $t;
}
```

and `$arr` will contain your array

After re-reading the question, it seems that it is not exactly the structure you want, but it can simply be turned into:

```
while ($t = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_tav)){
    $arr[] = array('id' => $r_tav['id'],
                   'data' => array('kid' => $r_tav['kid'],
                                    'k' => $r_tav['k'],
                                    'm' => $r_tav['m']));
}
```

Comment: i wish it could be such simple however as you can see there are nested arrays including data related with the same id

Comment: i updated the post with a snippet that should generate the correct array

Comment: this one is improved however how can i collect the data with the same id inside one array named "data" ?

Comment: that is beyond the original question, and adds a new layer of complexity

Comment: it is my mistake to fully wrote down the final array, now we have a solution. hope that it will help others with the same need. thanks for your effort